# How to inject data from the reques tinside my sql in Slim API

Tags: php, sql, angularjs

I have a Slim API and I need to make a function that will validate a username/password. I'm using a POST and I would like to inject the username inside the credentials inside the sql. I know how to do it if I use GET, but I'm using POST. How can I do that:

```
function authenticate($req, $resp, $args) {
    $credentials = json_decode($req->getBody());
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ict_users WHERE usr_username = 'Insert the username here'";
    try {
        $db = DB_Connection();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $password = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
    //check if the two password fits (use the password var)
    //create a session_key
    //Store the session_key in the DB
    //return the session_key
}
```

I call this function in a AngularJS service with:

```
$http.post(appConfig.apiURL + '/authenticate', credentials)
```

Comment: It sounds like you've got it roughed out. Plug in the code an see what happens. I would just return success or failure, but I don't know how you plan on managing your user authorization. You could also pull in Symfony's security bundle and use that. It's complex but once you get it going it's pretty cool.

Comment: The problem is that I already tried to plugin some code and nothing worked.

Comment: Unless we can see the code, there's not much anyone will be able to do help you.

Comment: I hadde dmy code and make the question more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
function authenticate($req, $resp, $args) {
    $credentials = json_decode($req->getBody());

    $sql = "SELECT usr_password FROM ict_users WHERE usr_username='".$credentials->username."'";
    try {
        $db = DB_Connection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $password = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        if(empty($password)){
            echo '{"error":"login_failed"}';
        }
        else {
            if (password_verify($credentials->password, $password[0]->usr_password)) {
                echo '{"error":"login_success"}';
            }
            else {
                echo '{"error":"login_failed"}';
            }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function authenticate($req, $resp, $args) {
    $credentials = json_decode($req->getBody());
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ict_users WHERE usr_username = ?";
    try {
        $db = DB_Connection();

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->execute([$credentials['username']);
        $password = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
    //check if the two password fits (use the password var)
    //create a session_key
    //Store the session_key in the DB
    //return the session_key
}
```

Something like this.